# Нужна ли здесь запятая перед «и»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, спп, и

Нужна ли запятая перед ***и*** в следующем предложении?

*Если положить объект в коробку, убрать её подальше(,) и ничего плохого не случится, то это, скорее всего, «Безопасный».*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая перед союзом «и» не нужна, так как он соединяет однородные придаточные предложения:

*Если положить объект в коробку, убрать её подальше **и** [если] ничего плохого не случится, то это, скорее всего, «Безопасный».*

[**Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении**](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=134#)

> **§ 119.** В сложноподчиненных предложениях **с несколькими однородными придаточными** знаки препинания ставятся по правилам, действующим при отделении однородных членов простого предложения.
> <...>
> 2. Между двумя придаточными, соединенными одиночными соединительными или разделительными союзами *и, или, либо, да* (в значении «и»), запятая не ставится (при этом подчинительный союз или союзное слово может и не повторяться).